# Searching a contraexample

Tags: general-topology, geometric-topology, product-space

> Is finite complement topology  on $\mathbb{R^2}$ the sameas the product topology on $\mathbb{R}$ with the finite complement topology.If $\mathbb{R_{fc}}$ denote the finite complement toplogy in $\mathbb{R}$  the question are $\mathbb{R_{fc}} \times \mathbb{R_{fc}}=\mathbb{R_{fc}^2}$

I´m try find a contra example, but I fail, to this moment I tried $U=\mathbb{R}$, $V=\mathbb{R}-\lbrace 0 \rbrace$ and $U=\mathbb{Z}=V$ but it fail.
If someone can give my a hint or in their case give me an particular example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HINT: Let $V=\Bbb R\setminus\{0\}$. Is $V\times V$ open in $\Bbb R_\text{fc}\times\Bbb R_\text{fc}$? Is it open in $\left(\Bbb R^2\right)_\text{fc}$?

Comment: I´m see your answer, but, I think that my problem if that I can´t see $\mathbb{R_{fc}}\times \mathbb{R_{fc}}$, can you tell me how can I imagine it?

Comment: @BrienNavarro: For this problem you don’t actually need to imagine the entire topology: it’s enough to know that the sets of the form $U\times W$, where $U$ and $W$ are open in $\Bbb R_\text{fc}$, are a base for the topology. In fact, it’s enough to know that they are open in the product. In my example, what set is the complement of $V\times V$?

Comment: The point $(0,0)$

Comment: @BrienNavarro: There’s your problem: $\langle x,y\rangle\in V\times V$ if and only if $x\ne 0$ **and** $y=\ne 0$, so $\langle x,y\rangle$ is in the complement of $V\times V$ if and only if $x=0$ **or** $y=0$. That is, the complement of $V\times V$ is the union of the $x$- and $y$-axes.

Comment: Thanks so much, finally I understnd

Comment: @BrienNavarro: You’re very welcome.